# .forceignore - How to ignore all .listView-meta.xml files

Tags: list-view, retrieve, .forceignore

I want to ignore retrieving and deploying any `.listView-meta.xml` files in my project. I plan to remove all `listView-meta.xml` files from my project.

I have been testing the .forceignore file with two methods of retrieval

1. `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ListView:Account`
2. In VSCode, right-clicking on the 'objects/Account' folder -> 'SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org'

When tested separately, each of the following .forceignore lines are successful at ignoring List Views if I use method 1 to retrieve, but fail to ignore files if I use method 2 to retrieve.

- `**/*.listView-meta.xml`
- `**/listViews/**`
- `*.listView-meta.xml`
- `**/listViews/*`

**How can I make sure the .forceignore file successfully ignores listview files when using method 2 above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because the VSCode Extensions for Salesforce do not use `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command to retrieve metadata. They do not have that logic built into them to respect .forceignore. This applies to any metadata not just list views.

They use direct tooling API and do not have additional logic to respect `.forceignore.`